# Seaweed Plugin not working

Tags: plugins, errors

I have installed the [Seaweed (Wordpress Plugin)](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/seaweed/).

I have successfully installed it and I can able to edit the content. But the save function is not functioning popularly. when I clicked on the "save button", the processing bar displays and nothing happens beyond that.

Has any one try it ? Could any one help me to make use of it.

Comment: Please change the title - it is not informative

Comment: Yeah, this whole question needs to be cleaned up...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions !
I have edited the question .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I read on the plugins description it's compatible with WP 2.9.2. Next to that I assume from the description that it interacts with the theme a lot. I would therefore install the [Default (Wordpress Theme)](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/default) and try if it works with that theme. Maybe it works with this theme?

Maybe you just run into a Javascript error or you have Javascript disabled? Please check these source of errors as well, because it's written that the plugin makes use of AJAX which means Javascript.

Comment: I have checked by deactivating the plugins which may conflict .But no use .The same problem persists .

Comment: Have you checked on the theme as well?

Comment: Same for me .I have tried it on Three sites. Two of them are fresh Installations .The plugin is not working on all these sites.

Comment: and @user391 I have checked it again .Now I can able to create new posts and pages using this plugin.But "save " functionality is not working on  the pages already created and when trying to modify the content .